# Point shapefile missing spatial reference information

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, shapefile, coordinate-system

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2. I've got a shapefile with points representing spot elevations in my study area. This file has been provided by a third party institution.

The coordinate system is missing spatial reference, as ArcGIS informs me as soon as I feed the file into ArcMap. I tried to use the `Define Projection` tool, but nothing happens, i.e. when I add other feature classes created by me (and that matches one another) the shapefile in question does not 'match' the rest of the layers.

As I tried to explore the extents under source tab in properties, the coordinates are shown as:

```
left 3199745.231567 ??
right 3219058.255825 ??
top 1064279.877094 ?? and 
bottom 1041353.944159 ??
```

When I contacted the source party, they informed me that actual coordinate system of the file generated is UTM Zone 43 N but as file was originally generated in CAD and then exported to GIS, its .prj file is missing.

Moreover coordinates shown in the problematic shapefile are not corresponding to actual coordinates in the right coordinate system (UTM Zone 43 N). For example: 'true' coordinates of a point 319907.40 E / 3720430.82 N, corresponding coordinates in the problematic  3212077.85 E / 1048297.355 N; so, the first is missing the one digit six digit as compared to seven, the second is showing different coordinates all together.

I would like to know if there is any way to fix this problem?

As I received that data, file with extension .prj is missing in the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem to be UTM, but rather Kalianpur 1975 / India zone I, which is valid for Pakistan:

[image]

The green dot (UTM 43N coordinates) nearly covers the red dot (India I coordinates). You might try other Kalianpur datums as well to see if they fit better.

Comment: Thanks alot AndreJ. It really helped as adding the relevant prj of Kalianpur 1975 / India Zone I has solved the problem for me. Grateful for the help.